# tf.scatter_nd_update Variable Requirement vs RNN.__call__ method

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-to-sequence

I am developing a RNN and am using Tensorflow 1.1. I got the following error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The node 'model/att_seq2seq/encode/pocmru_rnn_encoder/rnn/while/Variable/Assign' has inputs from different frames. The input 'model/att_seq2seq/encode/pocmru_rnn_encoder/rnn/while/Identity_3' is in frame 'model/att_seq2seq/encode/pocmru_rnn_encoder/rnn/while/model/att_seq2seq/encode/pocmru_rnn_encoder/rnn/while/'. The input 'model/att_seq2seq/encode/pocmru_rnn_encoder/rnn/while/Variable' is in frame ''.`

The error is caused by the lambda function in dynamic rnn method and a piece of code in my RNN.

- tensorflow rnn.py "dynamic_rnn / _dynamic_rnn_loop / _time_step" that using a lambda function to call RNN.**call** method to loop through all inputs.
- my code :

    `if type(myObject) != tf.Variable:
      tp = tf.Variable(myObject, validate_shape=False)
    else:
      tp = myObject`

Logically, i repeatedly use tf.scatter_nd_update to update myObject. The pseudo code would be like `myObject = scatter_nd_update(myObject, indices, updates)`. Since tf.scatter_nd_update requires Variable as argument and returns tensor, I need to wrap tensor into Variable. Hence the code above (test variable and then wrap). How should I modify my code to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: I currently solved this problem by creating a class variable Cell._myobject_tmp and then use tf.assign to assign tensor to this variable before calling scatter_nd_update method. My guess is, there are better ways. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: create Cell._myobject_tmp is extremely bad idea :).. I spent 2 days debugging this

Comment: Created Tensorflow Issue: 10855 - Differentiate Variable (Model Parameters) and Mutable Tensor https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10855